# Visual studio - Find assembly name easily

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I need to find the assembly name for a specific class in visual studio but i don't want to use any code.

How can i get that information easily in visual studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To easily find the assembly name of a class in visual studio, just:

- right-click on the project containing the class + Properties
- In the 'Application' tab, there's the 'Assembly name'

If you need more information on the assembly, there's also a 'Assembly information' button providing it.

*Might be a dumb question/answer but i didn't know my assembly name and lost about 15 minutes to find it, i thought i'd share.*

Comment: Well, unless you actually changed something, the Assembly's name is the name of the project

Comment: According to the timestamps that I'm seeing, you asked the question and answered with a fully formatted response within a minute.  What gives?  Are you answering your own questions to try and get precious upvotes?

Comment: @LordWilmore Answering your own question is completely [permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Unless you changed something, but let's say the context was i new on a project that was given to me where the project name was renamed, but i didn't know it.

Indeed, i answered my own question with the provided tool to do it. I lost about 15 minutes for a dumb thing, i thought i'd share the knowledge for the few that didn't know (like me). It's such a basic thing that it's not referenced anywhere..

Comment: @BradleyUffner Absolutely, but the answer came within a minute.  So we're looking at posting a question, then working out the answer and posting a formatted response within a minute.  It seems very odd to me

Comment: @LordWilmore Read the link I included in my first comments. This is explicitly encouraged. There is even a check-mark when asking a question to answer it before even submitting, in which case there would be **0 seconds** between question and answer.

Comment: @BradleyUffner thanks for the info, this is not something I've ever even seen but it makes sense so upvotes will be given.  I'll go and read ...